# In a Spring & Ball Game how do I make the Collider push the ball?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am making a game for my studies, But I have seen my lecturer and searched around for hours with no luck of finding a solution. The game works like this:

User holds down Space button and spring goes back a certain amount, simultaneously a variable called power goes up by a certain amount every Time.deltaTime (Every Second) to calculate how fast the spring will return towards the ball.

At this stage I have a Box Collider coming outt of the spring object that has its trigger function turned off at its Out position and Turned On once it comes back to hit the ball to avoid any collider glitches.

When the ball comes back it does activate the Collider but the collider does not push the ball.
I need it to push the ball with a different amount  of power depending on the Power variable attached to the spring. A condition of this project is that I may not have direct control over the ball so that eliminates the Rigidbody.AddForce method as the collider must give the ball its momentum.
Oh and both objects have rigid bodies.

Here is the script I have written If anyone has any ideas or knows how to resolve the issue Im having please do leave an answer or comment below.

```
    public int Points;
public GameObject Spring;
public float PowerPerSecond; // Increment To Increase Power Every Second When Spring Is Being Compressed, this allows different sensitivities of spring for different levels.
    void Start () 
    {
        // When Game Starts reset these values.
        SpringPosition = "Spring Is In Out Position";
        SpringStatus = 1;
        Power = 0f;
        Points = 0;
        Spring = GameObject.Find("Spring");
        Spring.collider.isTrigger = true;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        //Report Error To Console if PowerPerSecond is At or Below A Value Of Zero
        if (PowerPerSecond<0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("POWER PER SECOND VARIABLE CANNOT BE A NEGATIVE NUMBER!");

        }
        // If spring is in out position & user holds down the Space Button, Start Compressing the spring.
        if (SpringStatus == 1 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
           {
            SpringGettingCompressed();
           }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && SpringStatus == 1)
        {
            SpringReleased();
        }


    }


    void SpringGettingCompressed()
    {
        if (transform.position.x > -2.3)
        {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x - 0.05f * Time.deltaTime,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
        Power += PowerPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;

    }
}

    void SpringReleased()
    {
        if (transform.position.x <= -1.9){
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + Power * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        SpringStatus = 2;
            Spring.collider.isTrigger=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you could add a drawing or a screenshot from your scene with labels on it? I am not 100% sure i understand what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the rigidbody of your spring instead of the transform. Even if you cant manipulate the rigidbody of the ball directly you can still use rigidbody.AddForce on the spring. By changing transform.position directly you are bypassing unitys physic engine. Also use FixedUpdate() instead of Update() when doing physics-related stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am having a different problem now where the spring wont release after being held in.

Comment: I fixed the issue commented above but now I have another :(

how can I get the spring to stop moving once it hits the ball so the ball continues moving without the assistance of the spring pushing it.

Comment: Just tagged your name didnt know if it would tell you I commented back haha! Comment is above

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help I have figured out the last of my problems. I have marked the answer as correct.